# Use VBA run Unix Command with Arrays get Type Mismatch Error

Tags: vba, excel, unix

I'm using VBA to connect to UNIX and download a series of files from the server. However I encounter "Run time error 13. Type Mismatch" error with my "cmd5" commend line. The code is below:

```
Sub DownloadFirstRunFilesPart2()
Application.StatusBar = "Downloading files..."
Dim wsh As Object
Dim errorcode4 As Integer
Dim cmd5 As Variant
Dim FirstRunFiles(5) As Variant
Dim var As Variant

'Files that need to be downloaded
FirstRunFiles(0) = ProN & "_KSParameter_UserInput.xlsx"
FirstRunFiles(1) = ProN & "_KSParameter_SysOutput.xlsx"
FirstRunFiles(2) = ProN & "_ModelParameter_UserInput.xlsx"
FirstRunFiles(3) = ProN & "_ModelParameter_SysOutput.xlsx"
FirstRunFiles(4) = ProN & "_VarClusParameter_UserInput.xlsx"
FirstRunFiles(5) = ProN & "_VarClusParameter_SysOutput.xlsx"

'Connect to server and run loop to download files. Error occurs in "cmd 5" line
For Each var In FirstRunFiles
cmd5 = Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)" & "\PuTTY\pscp.exe" & Chr(34) & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & _
    " " & " " & pHost & ":" & ServerPath & "/" & FirstRunFiles(var) & " " & LocalPath & "/"
Set wsh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
errorcode4 = wsh.Run(cmd5)

'Get feedback and display error message
If errorcode4 <> 0 Then MsgBox ("Error occurs. Fail to download " & FirstRunFiles(var))
Next var

Application.StatusBar = "Download complete"
End Sub
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you should add a debug line that prints the value of `cmd5`. Then copy/paste that into a terminal environment and see if it works (I don't expect it to). See what error msgs you get there, then fix your code to eliminate error msgs, and get your process to work. Good luck.

Comment: before the `errorcode4 = wsh.Run(cmd5)` line, insert a line that does `Debug.Print cmd5`, then insert a breakpoint (F9) on the `wsh.Run(cmd5)` instruction/line. Run your macro. When execution stops, look at the contents of the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G). Does it look like a legit command? Adjust as needed.

Comment: I tried those methods. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is invalid to use a string as the index of an array, nor did you need to.

Assuming that all your variables have been defined in other parts of your code, and have module-level scope, the following slight change may make your code valid.  Use:

```
cmd5 = Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)" & "\PuTTY\pscp.exe" & Chr(34) & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & _
    " " & " " & pHost & ":" & ServerPath & "/" & var & " " & LocalPath & "/"
```

instead of:

```
cmd5 = Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)" & "\PuTTY\pscp.exe" & Chr(34) & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & _
    " " & " " & pHost & ":" & ServerPath & "/" & FirstRunFiles(var) & " " & LocalPath & "/"
```